# How to git push using ftp?

Tags: git, ftp, git-push

I want to upload (using only ftp) to my server only changes. I have a working git repository in my local. But I cant figure out any way to push using ftp.

I can use git push to send other hosting, beacuse it allow ssh, but this hosting only allows ftp.

Comment: `git help push` indicates that Git supports FTP. What did you try so far?

Comment: There is the Git FTP project here which provides a script for doing this, https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp .  Either user that or take a look at the source code to figure it out?

Comment: I'm confused with rsync, yes you are right, git supports FTP. Phillipp  please leave answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to push to a FTP repository using

```
git push ftp://host.net/path/to/repo.git/
```

Comment: Git-push version 1.7.12.4 manual specifically says: "Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols (in addition, ftp, and ftps **can be used for fetching** and rsync can be used for fetching and
       pushing, but these are inefficient and deprecated; do not use them)." That implies ftp is not meant for pushing and even fetching is depecated.

Answer (score 9):

The [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) script does exactly this:

> git-ftp by René Moser is a simple shell script for doing FTP the Git way. Use git-ftp.sh to upload only the Git tracked files to a FTP server, which have changed since the last upload. This saves time and bandwith. Even if you play with different branches, git-ftp.sh knows which files are different. No ordinary FTP client can do that.

Comment: The github link provided in this answer is incorrect (possibly no longer valid) - 404.

Comment: I have updated the [link](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) in question.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve written a little PHP script that heps with that. It si called PHPloy and is tightly-coupled with Git to determine what which files where edited/added/deleted and uploads them accordingly. You put your FTP details in a deploy.ini file and run just a command to deploy:

```
phploy
```

You can also deploy to multiple servers at once. And if you have multiple servers configured, you can select to deploy to one of them like this:

```
phploy --server staging
```

There is more that can be done – check it out on Github: https://github.com/banago/PHPloy