# Can I 'push' all the files in my git repository to my ftp server (live production)?

Tags: git, ftp

I just started (barely) to somewhat understand and use git. I'm using github and cloud9 IDE.

I figured out how to save (commit and then push ?) files to the github repository...

**question**:

`Is there a command that will upload (and overwrite) files from my git to my ftp server where my website is hosted?`

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886363/how-to-git-push-using-ftp), but I'm not sure I want a .git on my server (unless I can still run my site off it).

I've also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950107/git-push-into-production-ftp), but I'm not sure I can install anything on my server.

Is this not as simple as I thought it would be?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with having a `.git` on your server?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean dont want the file...I just want to be able to 'refresh' my live files, not just refresh a .git file (clearly I dont' understand git yet hahah)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git is not an FTP client. But you could create a post-commit hook to do this. A git hook is a shell script which is executed with certain actions. You could use this to upload all of your source files to your FTP server when you do a commit. For more information about hooks, see:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on the commandline - use lftp to ftp your files to your host.  lftp is highly scriptable and will allow you to add it to a post-commit hook if you so desire.

If you are using a gui - you can try filezilla or any number of other ftp clients to move your files to your server.

If this is a project that you want other to work on in the future, you can consider learning capistrano for automatic deployments and ease of releases.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23012886/195835), **PHPloy** is a great tool for sending your git changes to remote servers over FTP (you don't have to install *anything* on the server, which is great if you're on a shared web host).  It works from the command line and is written in cross-platform PHP (and even detects changes in submodules).

**https://github.com/banago/PHPloy‎**

From your local development machine, you just type...

```
git commit ...
phploy -s stagingServer
phploy -s productionServer
```

Done!

(Disclaimer: after using it for a while I've now contributed some code patches and improvements, making it Windows-compatible.)

Answer (score 0):

Whether using OSX, you can consider this GUI-based pretty convenient workflow (I also use for some WordPress stuff): http://eppz.eu/blog/push-git-to-ftp/

[image]