# Regarding push the code changes from FTP to git repo

Tags: github, git-pull

I have some of the queries in pushing the code changes from Server(FTP) to Github repo:

1. I have made some of the code changes in a file on Server(FTP)
2. After changing the file, I want to push the changes to Github repo(we have cloned the server files on the corresponding repo)
3. But I don't know how to push the changes to repo from server

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check following:

Have you committed the changes? (You have to commit before pushing)

Did anybody else change the remote branch(If the content on github is different, you cannot push)

If this didn't help you, please include the error message to your post.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I will check these points. But, If you read my question, I'm not sure whether we can push the changes (which is done on the server) from ftp to git repo. If there is an option, please let me know the steps.

Comment: And, according to the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886363/how-to-git-push-using-ftp/27530851), ftp can only be used for fetching and not for pushing.

Comment: I just want to confirm that I have heard that we can push the code changes from the server(FTP) to repo by putting git code (I'm not sure what the git code exactly) into the server? If this is correct and if you have known the same, please tell me how to do that